# find a pattern using regular expression

Tags: python, regex

This is example of a test I have

```
JT  - American journal of public health
JID - 1254074
SB  - AIM
SB  - IM
MH  - Adult
MH  - Biomedical Research/*organization & administration
MH  - Female
MH  - Health Care Reform/*history/*methods
AB  - OBJECTIVES: We assessed whether a 2-phase labeling and choice 
AB-  architecture intervention
OWN - NLM
STAT- MEDLINE
DCOM- 20120417
LR  - 20170220
IS  - 1541-0048 (Electronic)
```

How I can write a regular expression to identify only vocabularies after all lines start with "MH" and then import them  them to an excel sheet. The out put should be like this:

```
[Adult, Biomedical Research, organization & administration, Female, Health Care Reform, history, methods].
```

This is my try:

```
import re
Path = "MH\s*.*" 
re.findall(Path,file)
```

I know this is wrong, but I do not know how to solve it.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you'll need to do a few regexes since you also want to split on /* for some of the rows.  This should do the trick!

```
import re

my_file = """JT  - American journal of public health
JID - 1254074
SB  - AIM
SB  - IM
MH  - Adult
MH  - Biomedical Research/*organization & administration
MH  - Female
MH  - Health Care Reform/*history/*methods
AB  - OBJECTIVES: We assessed whether a 2-phase labeling and choice
AB-  architecture intervention
OWN - NLM
STAT- MEDLINE
DCOM- 20120417
LR  - 20170220
IS  - 1541-0048 (Electronic)"""

my_list = my_file.splitlines()

new_list = []

for item in my_list:
    if re.search("^MH\s*-", item):
        item = re.sub("[^-]+-\s*", "", item)
        item = item.split("/*")
        new_list = new_list + item

print(new_list)
```

Output:

```
['Adult', 'Biomedical Research', 'organization & administration', 'Female', 'Health Care Reform', 'history', 'methods']
```

I'm taking that string and putting it into a list.  I figure there is a good chance you'll have that string as a list when it gets imported.  I also like working with 1 line at a time with doing regexes, just easier to troubleshoot later.

I'm matching items that start with `MH` then capturing them.  I then split each on `/*` and put all those items together into a nice list you can use for your excel export.

Comment: Thank you. My file is not a list, it is a text file. I think I need to write " for line in my_file": instead of  "for item in my_list". Yes ?

Comment: Yep, you can do it that way or slurp the file in so each row is an item in the list.  That's what is great/bad about Python, always a bunch of ways to do the same thing :)

Comment: I've change the code a bit, now I flip the string into a list.  I find working with each line 1 at a time is easier to troubleshoot and write code against later.  Plus when you import the text, you might be importing it one line a time.  Lots of ways to do it :)

Comment: thank you. Can I ask why you used [] after MH, If I just simply write "^MH\s-" ?

Comment: Ah, good catch.  It should be: \s*-  meaning, any number of spaces (or none) and then a hyphen.  No reason to have [] as a character class.  I'll update

Answer (score 2):

Using `re.findall`

**Demo:**

```
import re
s = """JT  - American journal of public health
JID - 1254074
SB  - AIM
SB  - IM
MH  - Adult
MH  - Biomedical Research/*organization & administration
MH  - Female
MH  - Health Care Reform/*history/*methods
AB  - OBJECTIVES: We assessed whether a 2-phase labeling and choice 
AB-  architecture intervention
OWN - NLM
STAT- MEDLINE
DCOM- 20120417
LR  - 20170220
IS  - 1541-0048 (Electronic)"""

res = []
for i in re.findall(r"MH\s+-\s+(.*)", s, flags=re.MULTILINE):
    res.extend(i.split("/*"))
print( res )
```

**Output:**

```
['Adult', 'Biomedical Research', 'organization & administration', 'Female', 'Health Care Reform', 'history', 'methods']
```

Comment: Do we really need to escape that dash character?

Comment: Yes, I do not need  dash character in the final output.

Comment: No, I mean to use `\-` instead of simple `-`

Comment: @Andersson Not necessarily. You can use without escaping dash.

Comment: @Andersson. Yes you are right you do not need to escape dash

Comment: @Rakesh, what is the meaning of flags = re.MULTILINE ?

Comment: If you specify `re.MULTILINE`, you should add an anchor (`^` or `$`), otherwise it's pretty useless.

Answer (score 1):

Just posting code what I tried, before noticing that while coding a nicer answer was posted.
Please don't judge. That just happens on SO.

```
s = """
JT  - American journal of public health
JID - 1254074
MH  - Adult
MH  - Biomedical Research/*organization & administration
MH  - Health Care Reform/*history/*methods
AB  - OBJECTIVES: We assessed whether a 2-phase labeling and choice
"""

import re
import itertools
matches = re.findall(r"^MH[\s-]+(.*)$", s, re.MULTILINE)
splitmatches = [i.split(r"/*") for i in matches]
flattenedmatches = list(itertools.chain(*splitmatches))

print(flattenedmatches)
```

**Output:**

```
['Adult', 'Biomedical Research', 'organization & administration', 'Health Care Reform', 'history', 'methods']
```

Comment: why did put \s- in bracket ? is it okay if we use it without bracket. Thank you.

Comment: @Mary The `[\s-]+` a character class to match 1 or more whitespaces or dashes after the "MH", in one go. Since there's "  -  " after the MH.  Seemed better that using `\s*-\s*`.